# Determine Parameter Location From ParameterInfo In Web API Controller Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-4.0

I have an ASP.Net Web Api controller like this:

```
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    public myObject Post([FromUri]string qsVar, [FromBody]yourObject bVar)
    {
        return myObject(qsVar, bVar);
    }
}
```

I am writing a documentation generator and need to determine if a parameter is `[FromUri]` or `[FromBody]` based on it's `ParameterInfo`.

```
Type tc = typeof(SomeController);

foreach (MethodInfo m in tc.GetMethods())
{
    foreach (ParameterInfo p in m.GetParameters())
    {
        if (p.isFromBody ???) doThis(); else doThat();
    }
}
```

How do I determine whether a parameter has a `[FromUri]` or `[FromBody]` flag in an ASP.Net Web Api Controller method?

**Answer:**

```
bool isFromUri = p.GetCustomAttributes(false)
    .Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof(FromUriAttribute));
```

Comment: I'd recommend you take a look at the ApiExplorer class: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/05/13/asp-net-web-api-introducing-iapiexplorer-apiexplorer.aspx. It should give you everything you need to be able to generate documentation. Web API also comes with a help page if that works for you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/08/15/introducing-the-asp-net-web-api-help-page-preview.aspx.

Comment: thanks @YoussefMoussaoui, I initially looked into that it kinda sucks for a help page. I decided to use Swagger and I needed more control over the process to generate the json that Swagger requires: https://developers.helloreverb.com/swagger/

Comment: Hi @Greg please look at my question => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206833/list-of-controllers-and-classes-in-asp-net-web-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at the [`CustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.customattributes.aspx) property:

```
bool hasFromBodyAttribute = p
    .CustomAttributes
    .Any(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(FromBodyAttribute));

if (hasFromBodyAttribute) 
{
    doThis(); 
}
else 
{
    doThat();
}
```